# can not sign in itunes connect suddenly

Tags: app-store-connect

I just could not sign in itunes connect suddenly( 2 hours ago until now).
Even I reset apple id and password, it continue reported
Apple ID does not have permission to access iTunes Connect.

I could log on Apple Dev Center, and I did not do any bad thing.
Does anyone meet the same problem?
Is there a way to contact Apple?

Comment: Interesting.  I have the same problem exactly 1 year later Jun 18 2013

Comment: and i have it now :)

Comment: same i have it now, changing passwords doesnt help

Comment: I have the exact same problem - good to know, that I am not alone :)

Comment: I have the exact problem now too.

Comment: Same here. Seems like this affects many people currently. I hope they will fix it asap.

Comment: And I just hit it too.. Reset my password twice. Can't login to Itunes Store either. Apple phone support is offline until tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way to diagnose the problem would be to get in touch with Apple.

Here's a direct link: https://developer.apple.com/support/resources/itunes-connect.html